# why $ 1 - \cos^2x = \sin^2x $?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I'm trying to prove this result $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1 - \cos(x)}{x} = 0$$ In this process I have come across an identity $1-\cos^2x=\sin^2x$. Why should this hold ? Here are a few steps of my working:
\begin{array}\\
 \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{1 - \cos(x)}{x}\\ = \lim_{x\to 0} \left[\dfrac{1 - \cos(x)}{x} \times    \dfrac{1 + \cos(x)}{1 + \cos(x)}\right] \\
=\lim_{x\to 0} \left[\dfrac{1 - \cos^2(x)}{x(1+\cos(x))}\right]  \\
=\lim_{x\to 0} \left[\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x(1+\cos(x))}\right]
\end{array}

Comment: What do you take as the definition of $\cos$ and $\sin$?

Comment: Google Pythagorean identity

Comment: $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$ follows immediately from the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a Pythagorean identity and comes from $$\sin^2 x + \cos ^2 x = 1$$

Just subtract $\cos ^2 x$ from both sides and you have your answer. Now, as to where $\sin^2 x + \cos ^2 x = 1$ comes from:

Let's say you have a right triangle with legs $a$ and $b$. By the Pythagorean theorem, the hypotenuse is $$\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}$$

Next, $\sin x$ is defined as $\dfrac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$, and $\cos x$ is defined as $\dfrac{adjacent}{hypotenuse}$

So in your triangle you have $\sin x = \dfrac{a}{\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}}$ and $\cos x = \dfrac{b}{\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}}$

$\sin^2 x = \dfrac{a^2}{a^2 + b^2}$

$\cos^2 x = \dfrac{b^2}{a^2 + b^2}$

$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = \dfrac{a^2}{a^2 + b^2} + \dfrac{b^2}{a^2 + b^2} = 1$

Answer (score 6):

This is just a basic property in Trigonometry.
There are many ways to prove it . Here is one way

$\sin^2x + \cos^2x= \sin x \sin x+ \cos x \cos x = \cos(x-x) = \cos 0 = 1$

Comment: its wrong answer. To prove the  statement $\sin x \sin x+ \cos x \cos x = \cos(x-x)$ we have to use that $\sin^2 x+ \cos^2 x=1.$

Comment: @Leox Where am i using $\sin^2x + \cos^2x=1$  in my proof ?

Comment: Why  $\sin x \sin x+ \cos x \cos x = \cos(x-x)?$

Comment: I am using the formula $cos(x-y)=cos(x)cos(y)+sin(y)sin(x)$. And when we put $x=y$ we get $cos(x-x) = cos^2x+sin^2x = cos0 =1$

Comment: yes, of cource..  but to prove the formula you need use the identity  $\sin^2 x+\cos^2x=1$

Comment: No , we don't need to use the identity see the proof here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities

Comment: well,  ok. But there are different ways to prove it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another simple way to prove the trig. identity, we know $i^2=-1$ so we have 
$$\sin^2 x+\cos^2x$$$$=\cos^2x-i^2\sin^2x$$ $$=(\cos x+i\sin x)(\cos x-i\sin x)$$
using Euler's theorem, $$=(e^{ix})(e^{-ix})=e^{0}=1$$

Answer (score 5):

Let $F(x)=\sin ^2 x + \cos ^ 2 x$.

$$F'(x)=2 \sin x\cos x- 2 \cos x\sin x=0$$

Since $F(0)=1$ and $F$ is constant, we get

$$\sin ^2 x + \cos ^ 2 x=1$$

Comment: My guess is that, since the OP is looking for the limit of $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}$, he may be at a stage where derivatives of $\sin$ and $\cos$ are not proved yet/are being proved. So he may be looking for something very elementary... But proving identities using differentiation is a nice method, so you have my +1 anyway.

Comment: it is wrong answer. To prove the formulas for  the  derivatives  of  $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ we have to use the identity $\sin^2 x+ \cos^2 x=1.$

Comment: @Leox not at all. You can do it using power series expansions and it's easy. Power series is a standard way of defining sine and cosine functions in many older books.

Comment: yes, but power series are not basic things

Comment: @Leox but it does not mean it's a wrong answer... But I agree, in this case Ovi's answer is probably the best and the most accessible

Answer (score 1):

If you define $\cos$ and $\sin$ as ratios of legs to hypotenuse of a right triangle, then $\cos^2 (x) +\sin^2 (x) =1$ follows directly from the Pythagorean identity.